# подсчет числа значений в списке, удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: python

дан список `list = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140]`
необходимо осуществить подсчет значений в списке согласно условию, например больше/меньше 100. Желательно чтобы выводилось следующее:

В списке N чисел больше 100
В списке N чисел меньше 100

Возникли трудности с данной задачей и пока получается следующее:

```
list = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140]
for i in list:
    if i >= 100:
        print(f'В списке {(i)} чисел больше 100')
    else:
        print(f"В списке {(i)} чисел меньше 100 ")
```

но это просто перебор, а как сделать подсчет значений, которые будет больше/меньше заданного условия. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы не знаете что такое переменная и уже списки изучаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совсем для начинающих:

```
numbers = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140] 
# не используйте слово list для названия переменной
greater100 = 0
less100 = 0
for i in numbers:
    if i >= 100:
        greater100 = greater100 + 1
    else:
        less100 = less100 + 1

print(f"В списке {(greater100)} чисел больше 100 ")
print(f"В списке {(less100)} чисел меньше 100 ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140]
    

print(len([1 for x in l if x >= 100]))   
print(sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: x >= 100, l)))
print(sum(1 for x in l if x >= 100))
```

Вариант от @Михаил Муругов:

```
l = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140]
    
print(sum(x >= 100 for x in l))
```

Comment: `sum(x >= 100 for x in l)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = [int(x/100) for x in l]
print(f"в списке {res.count(0)} чисел меньше 100 и {len(res)-res.count(0)} чисел больше 100")
```

Comment: Тогда лучше `x // 100` использовать

Answer (score 0):

Ну, раз пошли "изобретения" разных методов решения этой задачи - то вот еще в копилку. С параллельным изучением функции filter

```
def is_gt_100(i):
    if i > 100:       
        return True
    else:
        return False
lst = [1,12,24,3551,23,35353,3223,4,5524,1347,98395,3,234,58,24,90,140]
sum100=0
sum(list(filter(is_gt_100, lst)) )
```

Результат:

```
Out[2]: 147767
```